# How to align paragraph tag to the right of table in HTML?

Tags: html

I need some help formatting the space to the right of the address. It doesn't seem to want to align right no matter what I do. I am a total noob at this and definitely need to brush up on my HTML, CSS & Javascript. Kindly help me fix this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
  <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</HEAD>

<BODY style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;">
  <table style="width:450px;" width="450" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody style="vertical-align:top;">
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-bottom-color:#4a6481; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:bottom; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#3b4908;" valign="bottom">
          <strong><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; color:#4a6481">John&nbsp;Dory&nbsp;Doe</span></strong></span>
        </td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-bottom-color:#4a6481; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#3b4908;" valign="top">
          <a href="{{logoURL}}" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="Logo" width="179" style="width:179px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://p7aviation.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/logo.png"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:60%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; line-height:18px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#444444;" valign="top" width="60%">
          <span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9.5pt; color:#2c2c2c">m:&nbsp;+971 55 testing<span><br /></span></span>
          <span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9.5pt; color:#2c2c2c">t:&nbsp;+971 6 testing<span><br /></span></span>
          <span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9.5pt; color:#2c2c2c">e:&nbsp;something@email.com</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; line-height:18px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#444444;" valign="top" width="40%">
          <span style="margin: 0 0 0 5px;line-height: 1.5;font-family: sans-serif;color:#2c2c2c;font-size: 9.5pt; margin-top: 0px;">Pier&nbsp;Seven&nbsp;Aviation&nbsp;FZC<br>D2-009,&nbsp;SAIF&nbsp;Zone,&nbsp;Sharjah<br>United Arab Emirates</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:60%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top" width="30%" valign="top">
          <span><a href="{{linkedinURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="ln.png" alt="linkedin icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
          <span><a href="{{facebookURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="fb.png" alt="facebook icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
          <span><a href="{{youtubeURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="yt.png" alt="youtube icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
          <span><a href="{{instagramURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="it.png" alt="instagram icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top" width="40%" valign="top">
          <span><strong><a href="https://www.p7aviation.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#3b4908;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#4a6481;">www.p7aviation.com</span></span>
          </a>
          </strong>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Do you want both paragraphs to aling left and right of webpage?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML align attribute is deprecated. So, you should use CSS property text-align. Add "text-align: right;" to all elements that you want their contents are aligned to the right.

Comment: I want the text itself to still be aligned left and the whole span tag for address to be to the right.

Comment: Check out his code. He is using HTML 4.0 Transitional. align attribute is totally valid in HTML 4.0 Transitional. It is deprecated in HTML5 not in HTML 4.0 Transitional.

Comment: @JonathanRayPereira you can use align attribute without any hesistation. Features deprecated in HTML 4 are: https://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/deprecated.html

Comment: @JonathanRayPereira You should try adding "float: right;" to a span tag that you want it to be the right.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet, if this formatting you want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
  <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</HEAD>

<BODY style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;">
  <table style="width:100%;"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody style="vertical-align:top;">
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-bottom-color:#4a6481; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:bottom; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#3b4908;" valign="bottom">
          <strong><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; color:#4a6481">John&nbsp;Dory&nbsp;Doe</span></strong></span>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-bottom-color:#4a6481; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#3b4908;" valign="top">
          <a href="{{logoURL}}" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="Logo" width="179" style="width:179px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://p7aviation.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/logo.png"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:60%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; line-height:18px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#444444;" valign="top" width="60%">
          <span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9.5pt; color:#2c2c2c">m:&nbsp;+971 55 testing<span><br /></span></span>
          <span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9.5pt; color:#2c2c2c">t:&nbsp;+971 6 testing<span><br /></span></span>
          <span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:9.5pt; color:#2c2c2c">e:&nbsp;something@email.com</span>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="width:40%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; line-height:18px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#444444;" valign="top" width="40%">
          <span style="margin: 0 0 0 5px;line-height: 1.5;font-family: sans-serif;color:#2c2c2c;font-size: 9.5pt; margin-top: 0px;">Pier&nbsp;Seven&nbsp;Aviation&nbsp;FZC<br>D2-009,&nbsp;SAIF&nbsp;Zone,&nbsp;Sharjah<br>United Arab Emirates</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:60%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top" width="30%" valign="top">
          <span><a href="{{linkedinURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="ln.png" alt="linkedin icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
          <span><a href="{{facebookURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="fb.png" alt="facebook icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
          <span><a href="{{youtubeURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="yt.png" alt="youtube icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
          <span><a href="{{instagramURL}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="16" src="it.png" alt="instagram icon" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:1px; border:0; width:16px; height:16px;"></a>&nbsp;</span>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="width:40%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top" width="40%" valign="top">
          <span><strong><a href="https://www.p7aviation.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#3b4908;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#4a6481;">www.p7aviation.com</span></span>
          </a>
        </strong>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I have removed width attribute of the table and set `width: 100%;` in table style. Also added `align="right"` attribute to cells which needs to be placed on right side.